# What are the basic sizes on which the responsiveness should be tested?

Tags: testing, responsive-design, web-frontend

I have started frontend development, I do use bootstrap but I am still not sure as for testing what screen sizes should I test my website on?
I want to know the normal practice to test the responsiveness, I used the chrome default feature to test it but still not sure if I am doing right?

Comment: You can try resizing the browser window manually. If that's not enough, use some tools like http://www.responsinator.com or http://resizemybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You did correct to use browser developer tools for testing the responsiveness but you need to test the web page with different browsers like safari, internet explorer, etc.. also on mobile devices as well to assure.